# How to reflect user property changes when using Firebase Auth?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Auth in my flutter app to handle authentication.

The problem I am facing is that when a user property such as "Name" is updated from one device, it's reflected on the other device only **after** a re-login.

I want my users to have a better experience than that, what can I do?

I have tried using `FutureBuilder` and `StreamBuilder` with future and stream being the current user instance from Firebase and they both produce the same results.

[image: The screenshots for some clue]